# Spring form tags. Enum i18

Tags: spring, localization, enums, internationalization, spring-form

I'm using Spring form tag library to automatically bind values from enum in my Model to FORM fields:

```
<form:select path="status">
   <form:options/>"
</form:select>
```

`status` is enum  field in my form-backing object:

```
 public enum Status {ON, OFF}
```

But in `<select>` tag I get  labels like `ON` and `OFF`. Is there any way to localize this labels?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I found myself in this situation today. I didn't find any built-in solutions. A quick solutions is the following:

```
<form:select path="my.field">
    <c:forEach items="${enumValues}" var="type" >
        <form:option value="${type}">
            <spring:message code="some.key.${type.name.toLowerCase()}" />
        </form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

If you need this more than once you will need to create your own tag.